# apt-get install -f -- Error: no space left on disk

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, disk-usage

I had  cache limit problems with GPG keys. A post here solved that, and now `sudo apt-get update` runs without any errors. Now `sudo apt-get upgrade` does not work. It tells me to try `sudo apt-get -f install` and when I run it I get the errors shown below:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get -f install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating dependencies... Done
The packages listed below were installed automatically and are no longer needed.
  linux-headers-3.13.0-35 linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-46
The following new packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-46
0 updated, 1 will be installed, 0 to remove 455 not updated.
2 not fully installed or removed.
You need to download 0 B/8.877 kB of packages.
This operation will require 63.3 MB of additional disk space.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading the database ... 1181689 files or directories are now installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.13.0-46_3.13.0-46.79_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.13.0-46 (3.13.0-46.79) ...
dpkg: error processing the archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-46_3.13.0-46.79_all.deb (--unpack):
 Could not create `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-46/arch/ia64/include/asm/cache.h.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-46/arch/ia64/include/asm/cache.h'):   
No space left on device.  
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already.  
dpkg-deb: error: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe).  
The following errors were encountered during processing:  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-46_3.13.0-46.79_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but you need to put this in English.

Comment: Im sorry I registered in both spanish and english version.

Comment: Anyway, tr deleting this file: `/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-46_3.13.0-46.79_all.deb `

Comment: Or just do a `sudo apt-get autoclean` to remove all no longer needed cached packages .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I free up more space in /boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

Open a terminal.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get clean
apt-get autoremove
UNUSCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
apt-get remove --purge $UNUSCONF
NEWKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')
ADDKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
METAKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
UNUSKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $ADDKERNEL |grep -vE $METAKERNEL|grep -v $NEWKERNEL)
apt-get remove --purge $UNUSKERNELS
apt-get install --reinstall deborphan
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I run it excalty and the log is here:  I've an full disk error: ´No se escribió un informe «apport» porque el mensaje de error indica que el error es de disco lleno
                                                                                                   dpkg-deb: error: el subproceso copiado fue terminado por la señal (Tubería rota)
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-46_3.13.0-46.79_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
´

Comment: Run first: sudo  rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb

Comment: It run prefectly after run first " sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb" and then run your's first answer step by step. Now i want to know what was happening ? I didnt run anything strange before or installing anything rare. I could note that you do an clear image of my old kernel and update it,  thanks so much kyodake yours 1,958 gold medals completely justified. Regards !!!